# Codeigniter: check for authorization before redirect to controller on routes

Tags: codeigniter, security, routes, authorization

I am developing a web application with `codeigniter` and I need to check for an authorization before any `route` call a `controller`. I couldn't find any thing related to that on the documentation.

Someone has any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter have a solution for the same - it is known as hooks.
They are like event handlers which are triggered on certain events like pre-controller / post-controller. You can refer to the document for such.

But what you need to do in your case - enable hooks in the config file.

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

Since you want something to be executed before the execution of controllers method, you can either hook to pre_controller or post_controller_constructor.

A Sample piece of code ofor you to refer to:

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
        'class'    => 'Security',
        'function' => 'checkForSecurity',
        'filename' => 'Security.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

What you need to do in here - now you need to create a file - Security.php in folder (hooks). In that, define a class Security with method - checkForSecurity.

Here, what you can do is - do your authorization before allowing any user to pass further. If you got any user who is not authorized to access a certain area of controller you wish to restrict, you can just redirect the user to login page or you can throw and error page to the user.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I will check this. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can create common controller "MY_Controller.php" and extend it with all the controllers.

- Your config file should have the variable as $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
- In the config file you need to add following code to load all class files inside from core folder

```
function __autoload($class) 
{
    if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0 && file_exists( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . EXT )) {
        include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . EXT );
    }   
}
```

- Create MY_Controller.php in application/core folder

Put the following code in MY_Controller.php

```
class MY_Controller 
{
    function __construct() {

        $this->load->library('auth');

        $login_check_uris = array(
            'users/profile' // users -> controller name ; profile -> function name
        );
        // check against logged in
        if (in_array(uri_string(), $login_check_uris)) {

            if ($this->auth->logged_in() == FALSE) {

                // check for ajax request
                if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {

                    $return = array('status' => 0, 'msg' => 'Please login to perform this request.');
                    echo json_encode($return);
                    exit;

                } else {

                    redirect('users/login'); // login url
                }

            }

        } else if(uri_string() == 'users/login') {
            // check if already login
            if ($this->auth->logged_in()) {
                redirect('users/profile'); // user profile page
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Inside $login_check_uris you have to put all your urls which need to be check against login.
- Then extend MY_Controller in all your controllers.